# Bounty question borderline off-topic, flag declined

Tags: support, scope, bounty

In my opinion, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295806/opencv-to-android-opencv-java) is off-topic. It is asking for **translating C++ code into Java**. In addition to this point, it is also a mix of low quality and lack of clarity.

Because of these reasons, I flagged the question for moderator attention:

> This question is off-topic (translating C++ code to Java), but I can't vote to close because it has a bounty on it.

The flag got declined with the following statement:

> That doesn't make a question off-topic. Low quality perhaps but not explicitly off-topic

I improved some of the formatting problems. But my question remains the same: Is asking for translating code from one language to another on-topic?

If there wasn't a bounty on the question, I would have closed it as off-topic or too broad (give me teh codez).

Comment: That question is very unclear.. at least for me. I would have voted to close as well.

Comment: If it's only borderline off-topic, it's probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be interpreted as follows: the moderator rejection reply says nothing about if the source question is off-topic or not; it is stating that the reason you provided (conversion from C++ to Java) is not specific enough to validate asking for moderator intervention. That statement alone is not enough information for a moderator to act on, to begin with it does not prove that the question is off-topic. It is merely arguably a strong indicator that it is so.

If you flag for moderator intervention, you should make sure you are basically laying out the situation on a silver platter such that the required action can be understood without first having to study the source question. It helps to specifically state what moderator intervention is requested. Should the bounty be removed? Should the question be closed? Something else?

To provide a background to that interpretation, I have this other meta question in mind:

[How should questions that contain links to an infected/virus page be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293973/how-should-questions-that-contain-links-to-an-infected-virus-page-be-flagged)

Answer (score 0):

How to translate something from C++ to Java is certainly not *off topic*.  Not even close.

You could argue that it's Too Broad, if you feel that trying to explain everything that would need to be done to translate this is too much to fit into an SO answer.

You could argue that it's not explaining what problem he's having, and that the question is Unclear because you don't know what he needs help with (this makes the implicit assumption that "explain everything" is Too Broad, which it very much is).